# how to run ioncube encoded laravel project on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, ioncube

I have download project from server which is encoded in ioncube.
when run that project that shows the error
I install ioncube but still project give that error
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BNuc.png)

Comment: We have to assume you didnt install ioncube correctly. But more than that it is difficult to say as you provide so little information. Or possible the wrong loader was installed

Comment: ok I  am checking for right loader